# How to register without email in magento 2 and login with mobile and password

Tags: magento-2.1, login

i have registered with mobile instead of email in magento2. now when am i sing in with mobile and password i am getting error no such entity email with website id 1. 
AccountManagement.php

```
public function authenticatemobile($mobile,$passmobile)
    {       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $connection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')->getConnection('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION');
       $sql = "SELECT entity_id FROM customer_entity_varchar WHERE value='". $mobile. "'";
       $sql_sel= $connection->fetchAll($sql);
       print_r($sql_sel);
       foreach($sql_sel as $sql_se){
           $cust = $sql_se['entity_id'];
       }

        try {           $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($cust);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid Mobile or password.'));
        }
        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        if ($this->getAuthentication()->isLocked($customerId)) {
            throw new UserLockedException(__('Due to multiple failure login, Your account is temporary locked, please try after 10 minutes.'));
        }
        try {
            $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customerId, $passmobile);
        } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
        }
        if ($customer->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired($customer)) {
            throw new EmailNotConfirmedException(__('This account is not confirmed.'));
        }

        $customerModel = $this->customerFactory->create()->updateData($customer);
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'customer_customer_authenticated',
            ['model' => $customerModel, 'password' => $passmobile]
        );

        $this->eventManager->dispatch('customer_data_object_login', ['customer' => $customer]);

        return $customer;
    }
```

login.php

```
if ($mobile && $passmobile) {
                try {
                    $accountManage = $this->accountManagement;
                    $customer_mobile      = $accountManage->authenticatemobile(
                        $mobile,
                        $passmobile
                    );
                    $activationStatus =CustomerStatus::PENDING;
                    if($customer_mobile->getCustomAttribute('activation_status') != NULL)
                        $activationStatus = $customer_mobile->getCustomAttribute('activation_status')->getValue();

                    if($activationStatus != CustomerStatus::APPROVED)
                    {
                         throw new \Exception(__('Your account is pending for moderation.'));
                    }
                    $this->customerSession->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer_mobile);
                    $this->customerSession->regenerateId();
                } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                    /*$value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($username);
                    $message = __(
                        'This account is not confirmed. <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.',
                        $value
                    );
                    $result['error']   = true;
                    $result['message'] = $message;*/

                }catch (UserLockedException $e) {
                    /*$message = __(
                        'The account is locked. Please wait and try again or contact %1.',
                        $this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('contact/email/recipient_email')
                    );*/
                    $message = __(
                        'The account is locked. Please wait and try again.'
                    );
                     $result['error']   = true;
                    $result['message'] = $message;
                } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                     $result['error']   = true;
                    $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $result['error']   = true;
                    $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();

                }
                if (!isset($result['error'])) {
                    $result['success'] = true;
                    $result['message'] = __('Login successfully. Please wait ...');
                }
            } else {
                $result['error']   = true;
                $result['message'] = __(
                    'Please enter a mobile and password.sarvesh');
            }
```

Comment: i can login mobile with password  if customer register with email. but if customer registered without mail than i can not login with mobile and password.

Comment: Sarvesh, have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: Hi Pushpendra i got solution but right now i am very busy i will post answer later

Comment: Checkout this, but magento considers email as main https://magecomp.com/magento-2-mobile-login.html

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of Magento validation function on customer email, you have to set a dummy email on the customer even you don't need it.

For example it will send out email , isEmailAvailable in

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php
```